# Convert Oracle encoding 1252 to utf8 in informatica

Tags: oracle, jdbc, utf-8, sqoop, informatica

Is there a informatica function or settings that can convert all Oracle string type columns to utf8 encoding when importing using infa mapping.
Currently, I'm using nested replace() function to replace certain chars.